# Setting up Looping Menu in Java with I/O

Tags: java, menu

I've been having an issue trying to setup a simple menu in Java with an output to a file. When I run this program with the menu choice "1." I get the output seen in the link. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Onpw.png)

```
public static void main(String args[])
          throws FileNotFoundException{
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream( new File("hello.txt")); // created 
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("1. favorite pie");
            System.out.println("2. favorite tv show");
            System.out.println("3. favorite number");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

            int selection = keyboard.nextInt(); // is javadoc comment precondiiton sufficient here?



             while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Input an integer"); 
                selection = keyboard.nextInt(); //if user puts in double will an error be thrown?
            }


            if (selection ==1){
                System.out.println("What is your favorite pie?");
                String favoriteFood = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Your favorite pie is" + favoriteFood);
                output.println(favoriteFood);
            }
            else if(selection ==2){
                System.out.println("What is your favorite tv show?");
                String tvFood = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println(tvFood);
                output.println(tvFood);
            }
            else if (selection == 3){
                System.out.println("what is your favorite number?");
                String num = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println(num);
                output.println(num);
            }
      }
```

Comment: `int selection = keyboard.nextInt(); ` is already blocking for input - why have the next `loop` as well?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are calling `hasNextInt` after you already received an integer from the stream.

Since you call `hasNextInt`, the program has to wait for more input from the console to know if there is another integer remaining.

Once `hasNextInt` starts returning false, it will never be true again in the future, because the fact that the whole input stream has been read and closed, it doesn't make sense to keep the while loop you make to check for input. Just remove the loop, keeping the following in place:

```
int selection = keyboard.nextInt();
```